# Excel VBA Copy from Read Only Workbook and paste to current worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure why, but my copy and paste statement is giving me a runtime 1004 error ("Application-defined or Object-defined error")

This is the line in question:

```
cs.Range(cs.Cells(2, 1), cs.Cells(lastRow - 1, lastColumn)).Copy _
    Destination:=pasteSheet.Range(pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow + 1, 1))
```

Here is my complete subroutine. I pass it the file path as well as the current worksheet - `pasteSheet`

```
Sub copyAndPaste(filePath As String, pasteSheet As Worksheet)
    Debug.Print "filePath = "; filePath

    Dim cb As Workbook
        Set cb = Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, True)
    Dim cs As Worksheet
        Set cs = cb.Sheets(1)

    Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = cb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Debug.Print "LastRow = "; lastRow
    Dim lastColumn As Long
        lastColumn = cb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Debug.Print "LastCol = "; lastColumn
    Dim pasteRow As Long
        pasteRow = pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Debug.Print "PasteRow = "; pasteRow

    cs.Range(cs.Cells(2, 1), cs.Cells(lastRow - 1, lastColumn)).Copy _
        Destination:=pasteSheet.Range(pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow + 1, 1))

    cb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try cb.Sheets(1).Range(cs.Cells(2, 1), cb.Sheets(1).Cells(lastRow - 1, lastColumn)).Copy _
        Destination:=pasteSheet.Range(pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow + 1, 1))

Comment: @StevenMartin that makes it worse. `cs = cb.Sheets(1)` so by saying `cb.Sheets(1).Range` it is no different than saying `cs.Range`. So why call `cs.Cells` in one place, but `cb.Sheets(1)` in another?

Comment: sorry i meant without cs at all

Comment: cb.Sheets(1).Range(cb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1), cb.Sheets(1).Cells(lastRow - 1, lastColumn)).Copy _ Destination:=pasteSheet.Range(pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow + 1, 1)) –

Comment: thats why i was wondering why you defined cs and then didnt use it until the offending line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pasteSheet` is in workbook `cb`, you have opened `cb` as read-only so the paste would fail?  Otherwise qualify `pasteSheet` with its workbook parent.

**EDIT TO DEMONSTRATE BASED ON OP DISCUSSION**

To illustrate, I have specified the arguments of your Sub explicitly within the code. Note these are my values for my test, you will need to make sure that you provide yours in this form.  Note that (1) `pasteSheet` here is fully qualified and (2) I have adjusted the (paste) syntax in the copy/paste line.

```
Sub copyAndPaste()
Dim filepath As String
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'provide your values
filepath = "C:\Data\\SOtestdata.xlsx"           'provide your values

    Dim cb As Workbook
        Set cb = Workbooks.Open(filepath, 0, True)
    Dim cs As Worksheet
        Set cs = cb.Sheets(1)

    Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = cb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Debug.Print "LastRow = "; lastRow
    Dim lastColumn As Long
        lastColumn = cb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Debug.Print "LastCol = "; lastColumn
    Dim pasteRow As Long
        pasteRow = pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Debug.Print "PasteRow = "; pasteRow

    cs.Range(cs.Cells(2, 1), cs.Cells(lastRow - 1, lastColumn)).Copy _
        Destination:=pasteSheet.Range(pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow + 1, 1), pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow + 1, 1))

    cb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried that, but still not working... I added a parameter and set `wb = ActiveWorkbook` and passed that to the subroutine, and no dice

Comment: Did you update all references to pasteSheet in your code, in this way?

Comment: Well, what's interesting is when I get the `pasteRow` there are no issues...but wouldn't this mean that there are?

Comment: Now I am getting a 438 error - Object doesn't support this property or method... so I'm calling something wrong somewhere

Comment: Did you include the file extension in the 'paste to' workbook reference? e.g. Workbooks("pasteTo.xlsx") NOT Workbooks("pasteTo").  Best be explicit about the source and destination workbooks I think.

Comment: I am writting the macro for Sheet1 of my workbook, and all I want to do is copy the data from the opened book and paste it into Sheet1 of this workbook

Comment: A couple of other suggestions: (1) If you are pasting into the same workbook that your code is in then use ThisWorkbook.  (2) Did you Activate your workbook before trying the copy/paste operation.

Comment: Check the Range(Cells... syntax in the very last part of your copy statement, it should have TWO Cells references, it only appears to have one i.e. Range(Cells(r1,c1), Cells(r2,c2)) and Range and both Cells elements have to be fully qualified.

Comment: The copy statement works fine, it's the destination paste that is giving me issues. Even when I separated out the two actions.

Comment: I don't really get it... when I count the rows of the `pasteSheet` it returns the proper number of rows... which means pasteSheet is clearly assigned to the proper workbook and worksheet. So what could be causing some undefined object?

Comment: @Adjit - see edit to the answer to explain with example

Comment: OH MY GOD... my PasteSheet was not a valid sheet... I declared it as `pasteSheet = Sheets(1)` instead of `pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`... thanks for helping me fish that guy out